# Crystal Reports 4.6 - Getting report with Unicode Character Encoding

Tags: sql-server-2008, encoding, vb6, crystal-reports, collation

I have a stable vb project that had developed with vb 6. I need to add new Crystal Reports. CR generates the report without unicode characters. So how can i fix that problem.

Things that I tried :

- I tried to set collation of the field by writing query dynamically but CR doesnt let me to write dynamic query.
- I tried to add 'collate' to the sqlQuery using CR Designer. DR doesnt let me to add query 'COLLATE' command.
- I could't find a property about changing encoding neither on CR designer nor on CR object of VB6.
- I tried to change regional settings of the server and collation of the database. Nothing changed.

Comment: Do you database fields use Unicode strings?

Comment: what you are describing may be a limitation of CR 4.6 (which is way out of date).